# Pure pattern matching

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I am building a function that counts of many times a character appears in a string after the `nth` position.

```
countCh ("aaabbbccc", 3, 'b')
val it: int = 2
```

In `C`, I would use an accumulator with a `while` loop. But I am trying to learn the F# functional face, where this approach is discouraged. 
So I used guards to test few conditions and build the function:

```
let rec countCh (s:string, n:int, ch:char) =
match s, n, ch with
   | (s, n, ch) when n > s.Length -> 0                          //p1
   | (s, n, ch) when n < 0 -> 0                                 //p2
   | (s, n, ch) when s.[n] <> ch -> countCh(s, n + 1, ch)       //p3
   | (s, n, ch) when s.[n] = ch -> 1 + countCh(s, n + 1, ch)    //p4
```

The coexistence of patterns `3` and `4` is problematic (impossible, I am afraid). Even if it compiles, I have not been able to make it work. How can this task functionally be handled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the coexistence of these branches is not problematic. They don't conflict with each other. Why do you think that it's problematic? Is it because you get an "*Incomplete pattern match*" compiler warning? That warning does not tell you that the branches conflict, it tells you that the compiler can't prove that the four branches cover all possibilities. Or do you think that for some other reason? If you want your questions to be answered accurately, you'll have to ask them more clearly.

Second, you're abusing the pattern matching. Look: there are no patterns! The patterns in every branch are exactly the same, and trivial. Only guards are different. This looks very counterintuitively within a `match`, but would be plainly expressed with `if..elif`:

```
let rec countCh (s:string) n ch =
   if n >= s.Length || n < 0 then 0
   elif s.[n] = ch then 1 + countCh s (n + 1) ch
   else countCh s (n + 1) ch
```

**NOTE 1**: see how I made the parameters curried? Always use curried form, unless there is a very strong reason to use tupled. Curried parameters are much more convenient to use on the caller side.

**NOTE 2**: your condition `n > s.Length` was incorrect: string indices go from `0` to `s.Length-1`, so the bail condition should be `n >= s.Length`. It is corrected in my code.

Finally, since this is an exercise, I must point out that the recursion is not *tail* recursion. Look at the second branch (in my code): it calls the function recursively and then adds one to the result. Since you have to do something with the result of the recursive call, the recursion can't be "*tail*". This means you risk stack overflow on very long inputs.

To make this into *tail* recursion, you need to turn the function "inside out", so to say. Instead of returning the result from every call, you need to pass it *into* every call (aka "accumulator"), and only return from the terminal case:

```
let rec countCh (s:string) n ch countSoFar =
   if n >= s.Length || n < 0 then countSoFar
   elif s.[n] = ch then countCh s (n+1) ch (countSoFar+1)
   else countCh s (n+1) ch countSoFar

// Usage:
countCh "aaaabbbccc" 5 'b' 0
```

This way, every recursive call is the "last" call (i.e. the function doesn't do anything with the result, but passes it straight out to its own caller). This is called "*tail recursion*" and can be compiled to work in constant stack space (as opposed to linear).

Comment: I tough it was problematic because of the 'incomplete pattern matching' and because of the 'Index was outside the bounds of the array' error. I interpreted the error as if 'p3' and 'p4' would have lead to two different and incompatible solutions.

Comment: Next time, don't hesitate to add details to your question. You get more precise answers that way.

Comment: I will. I even fould your [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496550/abusing-pattern-matching?rq=1) on patter matching abuse. In any case, thank you for this answer, it is straightforward and exhaustive as always. Are you a teacher? (if not, you should :) )

Comment: Sadly, teaching (a) requires a PhD and (b) doesn't pay nearly as well. ;- )

Comment: @FyodorSoikin but all that paid Summer leave! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to not write it yourself, but ask the library functions for help:

```
let countCh (s: string, n, c) = 
    s.Substring(n+1).ToCharArray()
    |> Seq.filter ((=) c)
    |> Seq.length
```

Or use `Seq.skip`, along with the fact that you can drop the conversion to character array:

```
let countCh (s: string, n, c) = 
    s
    |> Seq.skip (n + 1)
    |> Seq.filter ((=) c)
    |> Seq.length
```

Comment: That is surely the most practical approach, but for didactic purposes I would like to comprehend how to build it.

Comment: Thank you Anton for the solution you proposed! I still have a lot to learn on the F# build in functions!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the other answers, but I'd like to help you with your original question. You need to indent the function, and you have an off by one bug:

```
let rec countCh (s:string, n:int, ch:char) =
    match s, n, ch with
        | s, n,  _ when n >= s.Length-1 -> 0                        //p1
        | s, _,  _ when n < 0 -> 0                                  //p2
        | s, n, ch when s.[n+1] <> ch -> countCh(s, n+2, ch)        //p3
        | s, n, ch when s.[n+1] = ch -> 1 + countCh(s, n+2, ch)     //p4
```

Comment: ... though that function does not return the result the OP had as an example? For the sake of showing patterns, you might replace some of the unused variables with `_`

Comment: Thanks @AntonSchwaighofer, I see that the input `n` is a 0 based index. I've updated accordingly =)

Comment: Thank you Anton for your answer! It is useful for me to better comprehend the problem.